# Is there a way to attach file to Xero Invoice

Tags: php, xero-api

I have this in my code which is meant to upload jpg image to my invoice.

```
$file_name = "set-chains-glyph_78370-1551.jpg";
$remoteFileUrl = 'https://example.com/path-to-remote-file.jpg'; 

// Download the remote file using file_get_contents
$remoteFileContents = file_get_contents($remoteFileUrl);


$base64FileContents = base64_encode($remoteFileContents); 

$attachmentData = [
    [
        'FileName' => $file_name,
        'MimeType' => 'image/jpeg', // Update MIME type if necessary
        'Content' => $base64FileContents,
    ]
];

// Construct the correct API endpoint for attaching the file to an invoice
$url = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/' . $invoiceId . '/Attachments/' . $file_name;

$Fileheaders = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    'Xero-Tenant-Id' => $tenantId,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream', 
'application/octet-stream' for binary file uploads
];

$newClient = new OAuth2\Client(null, [
    'access_token' => $accessToken
]);

$attachmentResponse = $newClient->fetch($url, json_encode($attachmentData), 'POST', $Fileheaders);
```

The thing is that the image is uploaded but when i try viewing it the image looks broken and is not shown. I am not sure what i am doing wrong could someone kindly help with this.

Comment: You seem to be JSON-encoding the body contents and including the filename and type, where the API ref says "The body of the http request contains the raw attachment content, not xml or json data that is normally used to upload data to Xero." and the remainder is sent as headers. https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/attachments

Comment: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/attachments/#post-attachments seems to suggest you must put the raw image data into a request with the headers it specifies there. Not sure where you got the idea for base64 or JSON encoding, or including those other properties...was that just a guess?